# Find Limit of Complex integration

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers

How should we prove that

$\int_{\mathbb{C}}\frac{|G(w)|}{|z-w|}dA(w)\longrightarrow0$ as $|z|\longrightarrow\infty$where
$G(z)\in L^{1}(\mathbb{C})$ and $|G(z)|\leq\frac{C_{0}}{|z|^{1+\varepsilon}}$

I tried to separate the region $\mathbb{C}$ to $D_{1}(0)$, a circle
around $z$ which is $D_{\frac{|z|-1}{2}}(z)$ and $\mathbb{C}-D_{1}(0)-D_{\frac{|z|-1}{2}}(z)$.
Then consider 3 possible cases where $w$ can be and try to find the
lower bound for $|z-w|$ in terms of $|z|$(no $w's$).

I still have the problem for the case when $w\in D_{\frac{|z|-1}{2}}(z),$the
circle around $z.$ How can we find the lower bound of $|z-w|$ in
terms of $|z|$ with no $w's$ so that we can run $|z|\longrightarrow\infty?$